# Rewrite the foreach using lambda + C#3.0

Tags: c#-3.0

I am tryingv the following

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            if (dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains(sheetName))
                            {
                                tableName = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                            }
                        }
```

by using lambda like

```
string tableName = "";
                        DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(dt).ToList().ForEach(i =>
                            {
                                tableName = i["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains(sheetName);
                            }
                        );
```

but getting compile time error "cannot implicitly bool to string". So how to achieve the same.?

Thanks(C#3.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableName` is `string` and `Contains()` returns `bool`.

So the error is because of

```
    tableName = i["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains(sheetName);
```

What you can do is (but I think better options are available in linq )

```
string tableName = "";
DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(dt).ToList().ForEach(i =>
    {
        var s =  i["TABLE_NAME"];
        if(s.ToString().Contains(sheetName))
            tableName = s;
    }
);
```

Best of luck.